# Invalid JSON file - ' in text destroys the dictonary form. Python

Tags: python, json

I am coding in python.

I´m working with company data in JSON.
The problem is that they have inserted the name without scrubbing the data, so " and ' exists in the text format and destroys the dictionary references.

There are millions of companies so I need to scrub it somehow.
Is there any solution for it?

A fake example is down below.

```
    {'OrgNo': 'x',
  'CountryCode': 'x',
  'CompanyName': 'Company's name',
  'LegalForm': 1}
```

I need to change

Company's name

to

Companys name

Thank you for your time, Kristian

Comment: is the example you have shown is how the JSON file look like? (it's not valid JSON format)

Comment: *"The problem is that they have inserted the name without scrubbing the data"* - No, that's not the problem. The problem is that they created "JSON" by concatenating raw strings, and not with a JSON serializer. You don't need to change the company's name. JSON can handle all kinds of quotes in strings just fine. Let "them" re-do the export, but *properly* this time.

Comment: Also, there are no single-quoted strings in JSON. Whatever you have there, it's not JSON to begin with. It's a complete waste of time to write code that tries to fix broken data that fell out of a broken process. Use the time to fix the broken process.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I take a discussion with them.